# sap gateway for microsoft visual studio 2013 add-in install error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, sap-gateway, global-assembly-cache

i´m currently trying to install the **SAP Gateway Add-on for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013**, but I´m getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot find Microsoft.IdentitiyModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll in Global Assembly Cache

I´ve followed the pre-requisites on the sap page:
[Software Prerequisites](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwgwpam_1/helpdata/en/80/572a006e15425799df17b5c83eb24f/content.htm)

I did install the necessary .dlls to the Global Assembly Cache, except for **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll**. I can´t find it in the **Active Directory Authentication Library package**.

I´m trying to install it on a system with **Windows 10**, but do you think that makes any differences since in the prerequisites it says nothing about Windows 10 supported?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will also have to pay attention to the specific version of the dll.

The error seems to point out that it is unable to find the dll in your GAC, maybe it's an issue with using the correct version.